# How are individual seconds counted in Chinese?

Tags: translation

In English individual seconds can be counted by `n + one-thousand`:

> one one-thousand
>   two one-thousand
>   three one-thousand [...]

These terms are not easily found in any dictionaries though, any ideas?

How are individual seconds counted in Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Tianya forum post](http://bbs.tianya.cn/post-english-154748-1.shtml) reckons that the same formula can be used in Chinese:

> 一千零一，一千零二，一千零三

---

In the medical field another approach is common:

> 001 (零零幺)
>   002 (零零二)
>   003 (零零三)

If double o seven was translated back into English he might be called seven one-thousand.

Comment: 我认为按照中文的语速 零一 零二 零三地数大概就是一秒了 一千零一的话似乎读得太快了